# Display textbox length on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, textbox

I'm trying to display textbox length upon click. The HTML markup looks like following:

```
   <div class="title" style="padding:20px 0 ">
   <input type="text" class="form-control txtKeywords" maxlength="80" placeholder="Click on keywords to combine your title">
   <span id="displayChar"></span>
   </div>
```

Initially when the page loads I set the text of nearby span to following text:

```
  $('#displayChar').text("Title contains: 0/80 characthers");
```

If user enters something into the textbox, the changes are tracked by this event and corresponding value of textbox's length is displayed like this:

```
 $('.txtKeywords').on('keyup',function(){
            var input = $(this);
            input.next("span").text("Title contains: "+ input.val().length + "/80 characthers");
        });
```

This all works good. I've also setup HTML 5 textbox validation by setting the input property "maxlength" to 80 characthers...

Now I would just like to display the textbox length upon the td click in nearby table which basically displays titles of products and whom I assemble in the upper input textbox like following (this is the HTML markup):

```
 <tr>
 <td class="keywordClick" value="@item.Keyword"><h5 style="cursor:pointer;">@item.Keyword</h5></td>
<td><b>@item.Sales</b></td>
</tr>
```

And the event/code for assembling the title is:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".keywordClick", function () {
            var appendText = " " + $(this).attr('value');
            if ($('.txtKeywords').val().length < 80) {
               // somehow here modify  the span value to display .txtKeywords current length 
                $('.txtKeywords').val(function (index, val) {
                    return val+appendText;
                });
            }
            else {
                ShowErrorMessage("Title can have maximum of 80 characters.")
            }
        });
```

In this last even upon .keywordClick I'd like to show the textbox length in the span's text when a keyword has been added to the textbox (to display it immediately after on click event if textbox length is <80).

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: @AshishBahl not sure that I understand you correctly? Can you clarify what you ment by that ?

Comment: I think you have many `.txtKeywords` elements right ?

Comment: @Rayon 3rd time luck... No the .txtKeywords is just one input... .keywordClick elements are multiple ones, since it's table generated from controller action :D

Comment: Anyone guys? =)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a function to set **#displayChar** like below:

```
function displayCharLength (count) {
    $('#displayChar').text("Title contains: " + count + "/80 characthers");
}
```

Append the keyword on the click event, then get the count:

```
var currentLength = $('.txtKeywords').val().length;
```

Then just call the function and pass through the length:

```
displayCharLength(currentLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to work just fine:

```
  $("#displayChar").text(function(index,val){
  return "Title contains: "+ $('.txtKeywords').val().length + "/80 characthers";
  });
```